# When will an event occur?

Tags: probability, distributions, predictive-models

When will a certain event occur?

It is very probable that a certain event occurs within one hour. Using the following samples for the event to occur previously: `{25,26,34,56,72,76,76,86,88,88,106,148,151,151,161,195,200,214,215,215,220,231,243,245,247,257,263,265,288,295,314,339,342,342,353,368,407,413,436,447,469,470,472,505,513,557,566,598,609,623,663,676,683,687,776,789,850,875,921,1058,1078,1167,1255,1292,1952} seconds`

```
Statistical summary
-----------------------------------------------------
 Number of values          : 65
 Min value                 : 25
 Max value                 : 1952
 Mean                      : 443.107692
 Median                    : 342
 Standard deviation        : 366.221250
 Sum                       : 28802

  25.00- 300.29:  30  ##############################
 300.29- 575.57:  17  #################
 575.57- 850.86:  10  ##########
 850.86-1126.14:   4  ####
1126.14-1401.43:   3  ###
1401.43-1676.71:   0
1676.71-1952.00:   1  #
```

What statistical tool can I use to predict the highest probable time for the next event to occur? Simulate events using Poisson distribution? How?

Comment: What does your data represent? Is this the seconds *at which* the event occurred previously, or is this an (ordered) list of *waiting times*?

Comment: The data represent the seconds at which the event occurred previously, the list was sorted before the question was published.

Comment: Thank you. I would say that clarifies the question enough to be answerable, and have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step should always be to plot. Here is a plot of when your occurrences happened, a histogram of the waiting times, and a time series plot of the waiting times:

[image: plot]

The first thing that jumps out at us is that the last waiting time was enormously long, corresponding to the single spike at the far right of the histogram - this last waiting time was 660 seconds, *all* the others no more than 137 seconds.

The second observation (see the right-hand panel) is that waiting times apparently were already increasing before the very last occurrence. The *variance* of the waiting times was also increasing.

It seems to me like the first thing you should do is to investigate just what caused these two effects. Understanding this should inform your subsequent analysis and prediction. Did something change over time, and if so, is the change persistent, or will matters revert to the previous state, or something else?

You could then try modeling the waiting times with an appropriate distribution. The exponential distribution is commonly used for that, but since your data are discrete, you might want to model them as negative binomial (which describes the waiting times in a [Bernoulli process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_process)). You can include predictors using negative binomial regression, see the textbook *Negative Binomial Regression* by Hilbe.

Alternatively, you could use standard time series forecasting techniques to forecast the likely next waiting time. For instance, you could fit an Exponential Smoothing model to the sequence of waiting times and forecast that out, which will give you a forecast of 188 seconds for the expected next waiting time, along with prediction intervals. You can even simulate from this series to get a probability density for when the next occurrence will happen:

[image: forecast]

However, do note that understanding your data is definitely more important than finding the most sophisticated model!

R code:

```
occurrences <- c(25,26,34,56,72,76,76,86,88,88,106,148,151,151,161,195,200,
    214,215,215,220,231,243,245,247,257,263,265,288,295,314,339,342,342,353,
    368,407,413,436,447,469,470,472,505,513,557,566,598,609,623,663,
    676,683,687,776,789,850,875,921,1058,1078,1167,1255,1292,1952)
waiting_times <- diff(occurrences)

par(mfrow=c(1,3),las=1)
plot(occurrences,rep(1,length(occurrences)),type="h",lwd=2,
    yaxt="n",ylab="",xlab="Second",main="Occurrences",ylim=c(0,1.3))
hist(waiting_times,breaks=seq(-0.5,max(waiting_times)+0.5))
plot(waiting_times,type="l")

library(forecast)
model <- ets(waiting_times)
forecast(model,h=1)
set.seed(1)
sims <- replicate(10000,simulate(model,nsim=1,bootstrap=TRUE))

table_sims <- hist(sims,breaks=seq(floor(min(sims)),ceiling(max(sims))),plot=FALSE)

plot(occurrences,rep(1,length(occurrences)),type="h",lwd=2,
    yaxt="n",ylab="",xlab="Second",main="Occurrences with forecast",
    ylim=c(0,1.3),xlim=c(0,max(occurrences)+max(sims)))
points(max(occurrences)+table_sims$mids,table_sims$density,
    type="h",col="grey",lwd=3)
```